# Can't open locally hosted streamlit app on browser

Tags: python, localhost, streamlit

a beginner here, need help

Trying to run the locally hosted streamlit app but not able to open in browser

**Error on browser**

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.

Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

**Command**

```
(venv) E:\chatbot_project>streamlit run streamlit_app.py

  Welcome to Streamlit!

  If you’d like to receive helpful onboarding emails, news, offers, promotions,
  and the occasional swag, please enter your email address below. Otherwise,
  leave this field blank.
```

Comment: are you on linux ?

Comment: @AchilleG Judging by the `E:\chat...` I don't think so. :)

Comment: oh my bad overlooked!

Comment: Did you check if the port is in use ?

Comment: No, it's WIndows :(

Comment: I've checked through task manager, the port was not in use

Comment: My code below

import streamlit as st

st.set_option('server.port', 8502)

def main():
    st.title("Chatbot UI")
    user_input = st.text_input("Enter your message:")
    st.button("Send")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Comment: @ShafiqIrusath Why not post the code directly into your post by clicking on the edit button? Visit the <http://localhost:8502> URL after running your application since you set the port to 8052.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to run the app in specific ports:

```
streamlit run streamlit_app.py --server.port <your port here>
```

And see if the problem persists. If so, I would change the browser or update it.